# Minimum date against each policy

Tags: scripting, qlikview, qlik-expression

I have 2-3 multiple policies with same policy no like if i have policy 00/34 then there is 2-3 multiple records of this policies but other columns of this policy is different only policy_no is same .. i want to get minium date against policy like if have this kind of data

```
policy no  fromdate     todate     sa_year status month_diff status(what i want)
123        23-05-2019   22-06-2020  2019    LOST    13        new   
123        28-07-2019   22-06-2020  2019    NEW     11        renew
123        28-07-2019   27-12-2020  2019    LOST    13         renew
```

i want to do if last record of each policy todate is less than current date against each same policy then last record should be lost otherwise when todate is greater than current date then record should be renew ..  and first record of each same policy which has min date should be new .. because this policy came first time .. and point is if policy not complete 1 year then should be new .. if policy complete 1 year then status should be "renew"

i tried this script

```
    Load Distinct
     POLICY_NO as [Child Policy],      
     OLD_POLICY_NUMBER as [Parent Policy],
     sa_YEAR,
    [From Date], 
     [To Date],
     Policy_Effective_Year,
     month_diff ,

    if((Policy_Effective_Year=Year(Today()) and
    sa_YEAR=Year(Today()) AND month_diff < 12),'NEW',
    if(Min(todate),POLICY_NO < date(today()),'LOST','RENEW')) AS 
    STATUS,           
     FROM

table_1.qvd
(qvd);
```